# How to run a car radiator fan with a PC 450 W SMPS?

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, dc-motor, 12v, fan

I have a car radiator fan which when measured with a multimeter on a 12 V car battery draws 4.7 A. I've been trying to run it off an old PC SMPS which is rated at 450 W with a max. current of 18 A at 12 V.

The SMPS doesn't start when I connect the fan to the power supply while the SMPS fan starts running when there is no load. What would be the problem? Can adding a capacitor make the radiator fan start working? If yes, what values should the capacitors be? What is the right solution to get it working?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/445505/atx-power-supply-minimum-load?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

DC motors take high currents to start.  you'll need some sort of soft-start to get that fan going on that power supply.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more. How do i apply a soft start here?

Comment: it connects between the power supply and the motor and prevents the motor from over-loading the power-supply.

Comment: Please explain components what are they like. I couldn't find much information online for DC motors

Comment: I searched "DC motor soft start" and found several for sale.